Вопрос по C++ Windows form CLI .NET
Объявил активную форму в заголовочном файле (.h)
private: Form activeForm; 

Хочу ее использовать в функции
            if (activeForm != nullptr) {
            activeForm.Close();
        }

Но здесь нельзя использовать управляемый тип nullptr. Как лучше поступить?

Form^ activeForm

Спасибо вам большое! По глупости не заметил
